# PGSQL ROLLUP function does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, rollup

I am trying to create a ROLLUP function for certain columns. It is mandatory to use only ROLLUP and no other function.

Whenever I run this code or any code that includes rollup I get this error

```
ERROR:  function rollup(integer) does not exist
LINE 5: group by ROLLUP(tmp.year)
                 ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

My code is similar to this one:

```
select coalesce(tmp.year, max(tmp.time_root)) as time_key,
coalesce(tmp.kind, max(tmp.kind_root)) as kind_key,
coalesce(tmp.sizecategory, max(tmp.sizecategory_root)) as sizecategory_key,
coalesce(tmp.placetype, tmp.place, max(tmp.takeplace_root)) as takeplace_key,
sum(tmp.pc1) as pc1,
sum(tmp.pc2) as pc2,
sum(tmp.sumt) as sumt
from outside.something_something as tmp
     
group by rollup(tmp.year),
rollup(tmp.kind),
rollup(tmp.sizecategory),
rollup(tmp.placetype, tmp.place);
```

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using? `select version();` will tell you

Comment: I cannot reproduce that on any modern PostgreSQL version.

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3.19 version